# Image of sup/inf under Galois connection between lattices

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders, galois-connections

This is Lemma 2.4 in Pete Clark's [notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf) on commutative algebra.

Given two posets $(X,\le)$ and $(Y,\le)$, an *(antitone) Galois connection* between $X$ and $Y$ is a pair of maps $F:X\to Y$ and $G:Y\to X$ such that $F$ and $G$ are antitone (= order-reversing) and for all $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$
$$x\le G(y)\iff y\le F(x)\quad\quad(*).$$

> **Lemma 2.4:** Given a Galois connection as above, if $X$ and $Y$ are lattices, then for all $x_1,x_2\in X$
>
> - $F(x_1\lor x_2)=F(x_1)\land F(x_2)$
> - $F(x_1\land x_2)=F(x_1)\lor F(x_2)$

I can prove the first formula (proof below), but I don't see how to show the second one.  Can anyone show how?

---

*Proof of $F(x_1\lor x_2)=F(x_1)\land F(x_2)$:* Given $x_1, x_2$, for each $y\in Y$ we have
$$
\begin{align*}
& y\le F(x_1\lor x_2) & \\
\iff\;& x_1\lor x_2\le G(y) &\text{ from (*)} \\
\iff\;& x_1\le G(y)\quad\text{and}\quad x_2\le G(y) & \text{ from definition of }\lor\\
\iff\;& y\le F(x_1)\quad\text{and}\quad y\le F(x_2) & \text{ from (*)} \\
\end{align*}
$$
The desired formula follows.

Comment: There is redundancy in your definition: if $$x\leq G(y)\;\Leftrightarrow\;y\leq F(x),$$ then $F$ and $G$ are antitone.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark FYI, you may be interested in this issue in Lemma 2.4 of your commutative algebra notes.

Comment: Yikes -- thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I've been browsing your notes lately, it seems like the error is still there.

Comment: About your argument, Patrick, we have $F(\bigvee A) = \bigwedge F(A)$ whenever $\bigvee A$ exists, is what your proof shows (no need for last equivalence).

Comment: @Jakobian Good point.  I'll simplify accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not right.
Maybe you're overlooking some underlying hypothesis.
To see that that's not true (the second condition), consider the lattice $\mathbf L$ in the picture below.

[image]

We will define a Galois connection $\varphi : \mathbf L \to \mathbf L$.
(In this case, it's the same map in both ways, having also the same poset in both sides.)

Notice that in order to show that
$$x \leq \varphi(y) \quad\text{iff}\quad y \leq \varphi(x),$$
it is enough to see that $x \leq y$ implies that $\varphi(y) \leq \varphi(x)$ and that $x \leq \varphi(\varphi(x))$, for all $x,y \in L$ (this is a well known alternative definition—or characterization—of Galois connections).
These conditions are immediate if we define
$$\varphi(0)=1,\; \varphi(a) = b,\; \varphi(b) = a,\;\varphi(c) = \varphi(1) = 0.$$
However,
$$\varphi(a) \vee \varphi(b) = b \vee a = c < 1 = \varphi(0) = \varphi(a \wedge b).$$

Comment: Beautiful example.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @amrsa's example, here is another simple counterexample.

Take the Boolean algebra with 2 atoms $X=\{0,a,b,1\}$ with $a$ and $b$ not comparable, $a\lor b=1$, and $a\land b=0$.  Take $Y=\{0,1\}$ with $0\le 1$.

Define two maps $F:X\to Y$ and $G:Y\to X$ by
$$F(0)=1\quad\text{and}\quad F(1)=F(a)=F(b)=0$$
and
$$G(0)=1\quad\text{and}\quad G(1)=0\,.$$
The condition $x\le G(y)\iff y\le F(x)$ is easy to check for each value of $y$, so that $F$ and $G$ form a Galois connection between $X$ and $Y$.

We have $F(a\lor b)=F(1)=0=F(a)\land F(b)$ as expected.  But $F(a\land b)=F(0)=1$ is not equal to $F(a)\lor F(b)=0\lor 0=0$.

Comment: Very nice. It’s especially easy to see that $x\le G(y)$ iff $y\le F(x)$ if one realizes that each of these inequalities is equivalent to $x=0$ **or** $y=0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is false even in the basic motivating example from algebraic geometry.  For instance, there is an antitone Galois connection between the lattice of subsets of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and the lattice of subsets of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, sending a set $S\subseteq\mathbb{C}^n$ to the set $I(S)$ of polynomials that vanish on it and sending a set of polynomials $S\subseteq \mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ to the set $V(S)$ of points where they vanish.  However, $I$ and $V$ do not turn intersections into unions.  For instance, $V(\{x_1\}\cap\{x_1+1\})=V(\emptyset)=\mathbb{C}^n$ whereas $V(\{x_1\})\cup V(\{x_1+1\})$ is not all of $\mathbb{C}^n$.